# Keyboard creates different iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Having an issue with inconsistency with multiple iOS devices. The same code creates gaps when I click the TextInput `iPhone SE (2nd Gen)`, `IPad Pro (10.5-inch)`, but it doesn't create the same gap with `iPhone 14 Pro`. Am I missing something? What is the best practice to fix this issue?

I am on the simulator, but it is happening on physical devices (at least iPhone SE).

If I comment out the `behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding": "height"}`, it may look okay, but my original code (below is the simplistic version), then the keyboard is closing the input fields.

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const Issue = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding": "height"}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios"? 90: 120}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{
          uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613828330596-982c62f72e9a?q=80&w=2670&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 10,
          }}/>
      </ImageBackground>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default Issue;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it in react-native, but in native code you would subscribe to the `keyboardWillAppear` notification to get the keyboard's frame. Hard coding values doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I am unsure how to approach this, as it may not be related to a keyboard issue. Even having `keyboardWillAppear` may require hard coding values because even if the keyboard is closed, the gap remains. I am hoping that there is a decent solution (e.g., flex magic), as this should be a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding `keyboardVerticalOffset`, you could try and dynamically calculate it based on the device's screen size or the keyboard's height. React Native's [`Keyboard` module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard) can help you listen to keyboard events and adjust your layout accordingly.

Use React Native's [`Dimensions` module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions) to get the screen size and adjust the layout. That should help in making your app responsive to different screen sizes.
Use [flexbox properties](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) to make sure your components resize and adjust properly when the keyboard is visible.

> I am trying to create a chat panel that is super similar to WhatsApp or Telegram. There will be a background image, a `TextField` at the bottom, buttons, and so on. The screen already has a horizontal flat list that (I think) makes `KeyboardAwareScrollView` not very applicable. The solution you suggested is not working for me.

True: `KeyboardAwareScrollView` is not suitable due to the presence of a horizontal flat list.

You would need a custom solution that handles keyboard visibility and layout adjustments.
Try and use React Native's [`Keyboard` module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard) to listen to keyboard events. Adjust the layout dynamically when the keyboard appears or disappears.
Then, implement a custom [`ScrollView`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview) for your messages. That `ScrollView` should automatically scroll to the bottom when a new message is added and adjust its height based on the keyboard's visibility
Position the `TextField` at the bottom of the screen, ensuring it moves up with the keyboard. And make sure the horizontal `FlatList` remains functional and does not interfere with the keyboard handling logic.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

const ChatScreen = () => {
  const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(["Hello", "How are you?", "That is a message"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {
      setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
    });
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
      setKeyboardHeight(0);
    });

    return () => {
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (message) => {
    setMessages([...messages, message]);
    // Logic to send message goes here
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={{ uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613828330596-982c62f72e9a?q=80&w=2670&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" }}
      style={styles.background}
    >
      <FlatList
        data={messages}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.message}>{item}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        style={{ marginBottom: keyboardHeight }}
      />
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Type a message"
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => sendMessage(event.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10,
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  message: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
  },
});

export default ChatScreen;
```

The `FlatList` for messages has its `marginBottom` dynamically set to `keyboardHeight`: that should help not to get covered by the keyboard. The `TextInput` is placed at the bottom and moves up with the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering how I can get the full-screen height. Dimensions module misses the height of the safeview part.

Comment: I think I need more robust solution as I don't really wanna deal with the state updates. KeyboardAwareScrollView handles the gap, but now it blocks the input text when the input text is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Baskaya OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Honestly, I am trying to create a chat panel that is super similar to WhatsApp or Telegram. There will be a background image, a Text Field at the bottom, buttons, and so on. The screen already has a horizontal flat list that (I think) makes KeyboardAwareScrollView not very applicable. The solution you suggested is not working for me, but it was my fault for not explaining my problem well and not creating an accurate toy problem to put here. So, I don't want your effort to go to waste. I am going to give the bounty + accept this answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Baskaya OK. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative approach for this kind of layout, for you to test out.

Comment: Hi @VonC. Thanks a lot for updating the answer. I tried this, and everything is working except that the `TextInput` is getting hidden because of the Keyboard. https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/590826250431332352?codeId=v6gm1y0wyVlwz&origin=imageurlgenerator&card=590826250011901952. The background image is working fine for iPhone SE and Pro. Are you getting the same issue? 

My actual code is like this: https://gist.github.com/osmanbaskaya/a8b54818546e4db21b08925357327911.

(Sorry it is a bit unorganized and crowded - I am newbie to react native)

Comment: @Baskaya I have cleaned up the answer to leave only the last part (that I cannot fully test). Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, A KeyboardAwareScrollView component that handles keyboard appearance and automatically scrolls to focused TextInput

Example:

**keyboardAvoidingView.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
    export const KeyboardAvoidingView = (props: any) => {
      const defaultProps = {
        style: { flex: 1 },
        contentContainerStyle: { flexGrow: 1 },
        bounces: false,
        bouncesZoom: false,
        alwaysBounceVertical: false,
        alwaysBounceHorizontal: false,
    
      };
    
      return React.createElement(KeyboardAwareScrollView, {
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
        enableOnAndroid: true,
        ...defaultProps,
        ...props,
      });
    };
```

Usage

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import KeyboardAvoidingView from './keyboardAvoidingView'

const Issue = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{
          uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613828330596-982c62f72e9a?q=80&w=2670&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 10,
          }}/>
      </ImageBackground>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default Issue;
```

Comment: Hey Shivo'ham. Thanks for the answer. I think this solves the gap problem, but the keyboard is blocking the input when the textbox is on the bottom. It works fine on Android. KeyboardAvoidingView was solving that issue. How can I keep input text on the top of the keyboard?

Comment: just try my example,try KeyboardAwareScrollView instead of KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: I was saying that your solution is blocking the text input on iOS

Comment: I don't think my solution will cause any other issues. something wrong with your implementation

Comment: Just add extra space or something else